# Drupal: Replace 'login' to 'logout' in a menu

Tags: php, drupal, menu

I'm facing a problem right now,
I'm using Drupal 7 and I don't know how to add/replace a link in the main-menu. I would like the label of a link to change if the user is logged-in or not.

There is it, it dislay my menu with `<ul>` and `<li>`

```
$menu=menu_tree_output(menu_tree_all_data('main-menu'));
print drupal_render($main_menu);
```

And so I try to add one more link to that menu. (and it doesn't work)

```
//test if logged in on not
global $user;
$path=($user->uid)?'user/'.$user->uid.'/edit':'user/login';
$title=($user->uid)?'My account':'Loggin';

//item to add to my main-menu
$item=array(
  'link'=>array(
     'menu_name'=>'main-menu',
     'link_path'=>''.$path.'',
     'link_title'=>''.$title.'',
     'hidden'=>0,
     'title'=>''.$title.''),
  'below'=>array()
);
$menu=menu_tree_all_data('main-menu');
$menu[]=$item;
$main_menu = menu_tree_output($menu);
```

I hope my question is clear,
and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the same but used JQuery and css:
check if the body has class "logged-in" and then I used:

```
$('ul.dropmenu').append('<li class="loggedInOverride">' + '<a href="/logout">' + 'Log out' + '</a>' + '</li>');
```

much easier for me at least. The main reason here was that I had a custom menu for an internal section that was NOT the 'primary' links nav. So the idea might work as well for the Primary or Secondary links.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to do this through code...just add a 'Login' and 'Logout' link to the main menu using the UI, with the appropriate paths (user/login, user/logout), and Drupal's permissions system will take care of the rest.

Since authenticated users don't have access to /user/login, and anonymous users don't have access to /user/logout, the effect you're looking for will just happen naturally.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
If I want to do 'login' & 'Myaccount' once logged ?
Is there a way ?

Comment: In my experience you'll need the [Menu Token](http://drupal.org/project/menu_token) module to do that...you set up a path to `user/[current_user:uid]` or something very similar. Unfortunately `/user` is accessible to auth'd and unauth'd users so you can't just use that one

Comment: Hum, that's why I tried to do this in php, because I have enought/too many modules installed on my drupal. So without this module, is it possible or should I find another solution than this ?

Comment: It's definitely possible but it's a real pain to override menu links in Drupal. Whichever way you want to do it you're going to be implementing exactly the same logic as Menu Token so it might be worth having a quick look at the code in there to see if you can extract what you need and not bother installing the whole module

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help. It's a bit clearer now. I'll post my solution if I find one ;) Bye